# How to give response to command line using java

Tags: java, apache, command-line, command, command-line-arguments

I am executing command using java code. but once command start running it asking for some user input. I dont know how to provide input using java code. Please help me.

I am using apache **org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine** package to run command.

**Output after running command using java code :**

```
   [java] The ear file could archive up to: 17 MB in size.
   [java] Are you sure you want to build it? [y]Ear building was cancelled by the user
```

**Java Code :**

```
try {
            CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine(command);
            for (int i = 0; i < args.size(); i++) {
                cmdLine.addArgument(args.get(i));

            }

            DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
            exec.setWorkingDirectory(new File(dir));
            if (timeout > 0) {
                ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(timeout);
                exec.setWatchdog(watchdog);
            }
                exitValue = exec.execute(cmdLine);
            return exitValue;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e, e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to use [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)(..) that returns a [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object to you.

Process has getOutputStream() method that connected to the normal input of the sub process. A bit trickier to use and detect when your script is done, but gives you more freedom.

Answer (score 0):

Use system.in in java for accepting input values

Comment: but how can i give input after "Are you sure you want to build it? [y]" this from code.

Comment: syso(are u sure?[y][n]) use bufferreader. below is the link that will be helpful http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-input-from-console-java/